# Android Json and null values

Tags: java, android, json

How can I detect when a json value is null?
for example: **[{"username":null},{"username":"null"}]**

The first case represents an unexisting username and the second a user named "null". But if you try to retrieve them both values result in the string "null"

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"hello\":null}");
json.put("bye", JSONObject.NULL);
Log.e("LOG", json.toString());
Log.e("LOG", "hello="+json.getString("hello") + " is null? "
                + (json.getString("hello") == null));
Log.e("LOG", "bye="+json.getString("bye") + " is null? "
                + (json.getString("bye") == null));
```

The log output is

```
{"hello":"null","bye":null}
hello=null is null? false
bye=null is null? false
```

Comment: Do you control the JSON? Then don't send the username field and use the `has(java.lang.String);` method

Comment: This is a known *and intentional* bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13830

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Try with `json.isNull( "field-name" )`.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I would go further and say to NEVER use has(KEY_NAME), replacing those calls to !isNull(KEY_NAME).

Comment: @SkyKelsey: Why would you say that? Those are different things with different semantics...

Comment: You're right. What I meant was that most of the time you use has(), you really would rather us !isNull(). Most of the time you are checking to see if a value exists at the key specified, and that is better accomplished with !isNull().

Answer (score 19):

Because JSONObject#getString returns a value if the given key exists, it is not null by definition.  This is the reason JSONObject.NULL exists: to represent a null JSON value.

```
json.getString("hello").equals(JSONObject.NULL); // should be false
json.getString("bye").equals(JSONObject.NULL); // should be true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but imho and since an JSONException is thrown if the key don't exists is more logical returning null when the item is null

Comment: You'll need to take up stylistic preferences with the developers of the library itself :p

Comment: "null" != null. The problem is that isNull needs api 9+ and sometimes you want lower apis to work. This answer is well, you can use jsonObject.getString != "null" to.

Answer (score 16):

For android it will raise an JSONException if no such mapping exists. So you can't call this method directly.

```
json.getString("bye")
```

if you data can be empty(may not exist the key), try

```
json.optString("bye","callback string");
```

or

```
json.optString("bye");
```

instead.

In your demo code, the

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"hello\":null}");
json.getString("hello");
```

this you get is String "null" not null.

your shoud use

```
if(json.isNull("hello")) {
    helloStr = null;
} else {
    helloStr = json.getString("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

first check with `isNull()`....if cant work then try belows

and also you have `JSONObject.NULL` to check null value...

```
 if ((resultObject.has("username")
    && null != resultObject.getString("username")
    && resultObject.getString("username").trim().length() != 0)
      {
               //not null
        }
```

and in your case also check `resultObject.getString("username").trim().eqauls("null")`

Comment: Simplified as "if(!resultObject.isNull("username") && resultObject.getString("username").trim().length() != 0)"

Answer (score 3):

If you must parse json first and handle object later, let try this

Parser

```
Object data = json.get("username");
```

Handler

```
if (data instanceof Integer || data instanceof Double || data instanceof Long) {
     // handle number ;
} else if (data instanceof String) {
     // hanle string;               
} else if (data == JSONObject.NULL) {
     // hanle null;                 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a helper method I use so that I can get JSON strings with only one line of code:

```
public String getJsonString(JSONObject jso, String field) {
    if(jso.isNull(field))
        return null;
    else
        try {
            return jso.getString(field);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            LogHelper.e("model", "Error parsing value");
            return null;
        }
}
```

and then something like this:

```
String mFirstName = getJsonString(jsonObject, "first_name");
```

would give you your string value or safely set your string variable to null.  I use Gson whenever I can to avoid pitfalls like these.  It handles null values much better in my opinion.