# How to handle null response for json array in android

Tags: android, json

I got a json response as

```
 {
    "tasks": null,
    "projects": null

  }
```

how to check if the array has null values and handle the case??

Thanks:)

Comment: array means? you mean response null or particular field null?

Comment: @SathishKumar: Assume that "tasks" and "projects" are normally arrays, but in this example they are both set to null.

Comment: particular field.here tasks is json array.It returns the value null when there is no data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588763/android-json-and-null-values check this,

Comment: Hi Can you Update The full String With Root This data coming from the Array Or Jsonobject

Comment: Hii I Update My Ans Please Try This It Works Properly.

Comment: @SathishKumar This link is working like awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
jsonObject.isNull("field-name")
```

Reference: [JSON null handling](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10588785/2451524).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
=============
try {
        String url;
    JSONObject JsonData = new JSONObject("YOUR FULL JSONSTRING");
    JSONArray webData = JsonData.getJSONArray("YOUR ROOT NAME OF YOUR JSON RESPONSE");

    for(int i=0;i<webData.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject TeampObj = webData.getJSONObject(i);
        if(TeampObj.getString("tasks").trim().length()>0)
        {
            //store data in arrylist or string array

        }
        if(TeampObj.getString("projects").trim().length()>0)
        {
            //store data in arrylist or string array
        }
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Give me your Fuul String i send you Full Parsing

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
 public boolean isNull (String name)
```

Added in API level 1
Returns true if this object has no mapping for name or if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

use try ... catch to handle the exception:

```
Try{

   // parsing data

}catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```