# How to handle null response from the JSON data?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-sqlite, content-values

I have a method for saving the values to ContentValues from remote server data as shown below:

```
public static ContentValues platformInfoToContentValues(@NonNull 
    GamePlatformInfoList platform) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_ID, platform.id());
        values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_NAME, platform.name());
        values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_ORIGINAL_PRICE, platform.original_price());
        values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_RELEASE_DATE, platform.release_date());
        values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_COMPANY_NAME, platform.company().name());
        values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_SMALL_IMAGE, platform.image().small_url());
        values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_MEDIUM_IMAGE, platform.image().medium_url());
        values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_HD_IMAGE, platform.image().super_url());

        return values;
}
```

In the last line the **platform.company()** value is null which is responsible for crashing my app.

My `JSON` data is in the following format:

**{
  "company": null,
  "name": "PC",
}**

Here, the platform is GamePlatformInfoList data object which inturn "HAS-A" company as GameCompanyInfoShort data object inside it. Hence, I am using it as "platform.company().name()". How should I check for null before accessing "name()" property? Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Json and null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588763/android-json-and-null-values)

Comment: if (platform.company() != null) ?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi -  Will try this once..

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting your json simply write this

```
if(jsonObject.getString("company")!=null){
     // do your thing here
 }
```

You can also do this `json.isNull( "field-name" )` .

Comment: Actually, I am using Google's AutoValue library to automatically convert the JSON to JSONObject. I tried all the responses given here, but it is unable to answer my question. The parameter which I have passed in the method "GamePlatformInfoList platform" is already a JSON Object but I could find the methods isNull() or getString() to check for "null".

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.length() == 0
```

or

```
if (jsonObject.isNull("company"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the ternary operator to handle null as shown below.

```
values.put(TrackedPlatformEntry.COLUMN_PLATFORM_COMPANY_NAME, platform.company() != null ? platform.company().name() : "UNKNOWN COMPANY");
```

It worked for me.