# In JSON file 2 values are missing in a object. How to handel it

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Here is my main activity.

In an object no name and skills are given. Its causing `IllegalArgumentException`. How to handle this.how to add if clause in this case. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588763/android-json-and-null-values) but it is different.

```
JSONArray personsArray=response.getJSONArray ("data");
                    Log.d(TAG, personsArray.toString());
                    for (int i=0;i<personsArray.length ();i++)
                    { JSONObject jo = personsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        arrayList.add(new Person (

                                jo.optString ("name","No name"),
                                jo.optString ("skills","No skills"),
                                jo.optString ("image","NullvalueURL")));
```

My json file contains like this // posting a fragment of my json

```
 {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Raghuram Rajan",
      "skills": " Economist",
      "image": "https://teekhapan.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/raghuram-rajan.jpg?w=229&h=300"
    },
    {
      "skills": "Dancer"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Raghuram Rajan",
      "skills": " Economist",
      "image":
```

Error log cat which showing path must not be empty

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.satyajit.nevalabassignment, PID: 25319
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:297)
    at com.satyajit.nevalabassignment.Models.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:46)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2404)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:750)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5333)
    at android.widget.ListView.trackMotionScroll(ListView.java:1971)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3628)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:4060)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3873)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2965)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2965)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2965)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2965)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1848)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3315)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:408)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4855)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4638)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4169)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4222)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4188)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4315)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4372)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4169)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4222)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4188)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4169)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6743)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6717)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6663)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6846)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:177)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6817)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6869)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1039)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:851)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:736)
    02-10 00:29:43.277 25319-25319/com.satyajit.nevalabassignment E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1025)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: add a proper JSON. or edit it.

Comment: i cant edit the json..i have to manage my code...

Comment: I mean the code in here. it is wrong formatted.

Comment: just added try catch and the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is not from parsing the JSON, but from trying to load an image that does not exist. Before invoking Picasso to load the image (I suppose you use the image url from JSON for that), check if that image url is not null, resp. equal to your "NullvalueURL".